# Count labels for the `scale_x_binned` histogram in ggplot 3.3.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

In version [3.3.0 of ggplot2](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#new-bin-scale), we now have the `scale_*_binned` binning scales. This is useful when creating a more visually appealing histogram

- How can I add labels on the histogram bars indicating the counts?

What do I put in the labels argument in `+ geom_text(aes(label = ...))`

I have the feeling that the answer is somewhere in the saved objects in the ggplot object `p` (see below) in the form of a calculated quantity somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3

p <- 
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(mpg)) +
  scale_x_binned()

p
```

[image]

```r
names(p)
#> [1] "data"        "layers"      "scales"      "mapping"     "theme"      
#> [6] "coordinates" "facet"       "plot_env"    "labels"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels for the counts can be added via `geom_text(aes(x = mpg, label = ..count..), stat = "count")`. Try this

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- 
  ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(mpg)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = mpg, label = ..count..), stat = "count", vjust = -.2) +
  scale_x_binned()

p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid it would be that. I never used the `...count..` thing in  `geom_bar` . I always precalculated the counts.... Thanks again